# Electron - Erro 400 ao obter geolocalização

Tags: electron, geolocalização, quasar

Estou tentando utilizar o `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` e o `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` em um projeto PWA feito com o Quasar.

Está funcionando muito bem no Browser e no Cordova (Android), porem acontece um erro ao publicar no Electron.:

```
PositionError {
  code: 2, 
  message: "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400."
}
```

Note que é um Erro `400 (Bad Request)` e não `403 (Forbidden)`, ou seja, não é um problema com a minha chave da `API do Google`.

Em todo caso, segue o trecho do arquivo `main.js` onde a API está sendo configurada.:

```
'use strict'
const
  electron = require('electron'),
  path = require('path'),
  config = require('../config/electron'),
  app = electron.app,
  BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

let mainWindow
function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ...
  })
  ...
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'blablabla'
process.env.GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID = 'blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com'
process.env.GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET = 'blablabla'
app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

Quanto realizo a chamada direto pelo RestMan, ele retorna a localização sem problemas.:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{}' https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=blablabla
{
    "location": {
        "lat": -x.fffffff,
        "lng": -y.fffffff
    },
    "accuracy": fff
}
```

Comment: **Não** tenho certeza, mas creio que seja um bug na versão 58.0.3029.110 do Chromium (atualmente a versão que o Electron usa), esse bug foi corrigido creio eu na versão 61, então só quando eles atualizarem o Chromium para uma versão mais nova que a 61 para corrigir o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema ocorria ao setar as `variáveis de ambiente`, ao elas `processo principal (main.js)`, elas não estavam sendo refletidas para o processo de renderização.

A minha primeira tentativa, foi mover as mesmas para o processo de build do WebPack.:

**`./config/prod.env.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  GOOGLE_API_KEY: '"blablabla"',
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID: '"blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com"',
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET: '"blablabla"'
}
```

**`./electron/config/webpack.conf.js`**

```
var ... config = require('../config/webpack') ...
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': config.env
    })
    ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

Porém o erro continuava, ao tentar acessar o `process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY` pelo DevTools, continuava a exibir o chave padrão adotada pelo Electron.:

porem identifique que o seguinte condigo.:

```
if (this.$q.platform.is.electron) {
  let values = process.env
  console.log(process.env)
}
```

era transpirado para.:

```
var values = Object({
  NODE_ENV: "production",
  GOOGLE_API_KEY: "blablabla",
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID: "blablabla.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET: "blablabla"
});
```

Então como **solução de contorno**, precisei setar as variáveis de ambiente.:

```
if (this.$q.platform.is.electron) {
  let values = process.env
  eval("\
    let electron = require('electron');\n\
    Object.keys(values).forEach(function (key) {\n\
      process.env[key] = electron.remote.process.env[key] = values[key]\n\
    });\n\
  ")
}
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento agora preciso encontrar uma forma de me livrar desta gambiarra.